# How to hard reset the VoCore2 Ultimate?

Tags: reset

A student of mine was trying to configure the VoCore2 Ultimate but somehow managed to lock us out.

He said something about a static IP address, I did not understand what exactly and I frankly don't think he knows what he did. The WiFi is enabled, but impossible to use it.

Is there a was to hard reset it? There is no way I can SSH to it to reset the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained on the [manufacturer's site](http://vocore.io/v2u.html), you can connect to it's console via USB:

> VoCore2 Ultimate, VoCore2 Audio have on board USB2TTL, you can directly connect its microUSB and your computer.

They provide a link to a [YouTube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3UVXb5YM2k).

Basically:

- Plug it in via USB.
- Install the driver (Windows 10 may do it automatically, but otherwise the manufacturer provides drivers for various OSs on their site).
- Fire up a terminal program (PuTTY should work).
- Set it up for a Serial connection of "115200bps, 8 data bits, no even-odd check, 1 stop bit".
- Connect to device.

You should now have console access so you can reset the networking (etc.).

Comment: Question: Your answer is helpful for someone with the dock version but there is a Vocore which lacks the dock. I have a Vocore without a dock and I need to establish communication through USB so I can use the wireless network interface to connect to another access point to get the Vocore online. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes

As listed [here](https://www.router-reset.com/en/reset-manuals/Vonger-Electronics/Vocore2-Ultimate#factory-reset-instructions) the instructions state:

> The 30-30-30 reset
>
> There are no specific instructions for this model yet, but you can
> always do the 30-30-30 reset as follows:
>
> When router is powered on, press the reset button and hold for 30 seconds.
> (Use a paper clip or something sharp)
>
> While holding the reset button pressed, unplug the power of the router and hold the reset button for 30 seconds
>
> While still holding the reset button down, turn on the power to the unit again and hold for another 30 seconds.

And then you can login with the defaults:

> If you have performed a reset of your Vocore2 Ultimate device or not
> changed the defaults, you should be able to access it with the
> following settings:
>
> Default Network name (SSID): VoCore2
>
> Default Gateway IP: 192.168.1.1
>
> Default admin username: root
>
> Default admin password: vocore
>
> Default subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
>
> Default DNS server: 192.168.1.1
>
> Note: If you are using the default settings you should change them to increase
> security and prevent unathorized access to your network.

Comment: The Vocore is not a traditional router. The instructions within the linked page state "There are no specific instructions for this model yet...". There is no physical reset button the Vocore. The official website is found @ http://vocore.io